# Value empty when radio element disabled on Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a Zend Form with one of the elements shown as disabled and is not editable by the user.

```
        $gender = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('gender');
        $gender->setLabel('Gender')
               ->setMultiOptions(array(
                    'Male' => 'Male',
                    'Female' => 'Female'
                ));
        $gender->setRequired(true);
        $gender->setAttrib('disabled', 'true');
```

In my case, when i have updated, the value in my database become empty for gender row. Example : I set gender to 'Male' and after updated another elements, gender data on my database is lost. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

A disabled input is not posted on submit.
You may use a readonly input instead.

Comment: I have tried but still not working. I also read some references, a radio element cannot use readonly input